# External api call using python in cloud function

Tags: python-3.x

```python
def hello_gcs(data, context):
    from google.cloud import storage
    list_object=[]
    import re
    list_jpg=[]
    list_flac=[]
    list_json=[]

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs('recorded-videos-audios')
    for blob in blobs:
        list_object.append(blob.name)

    print(list_object) # printng all files of bucket
```

I want to call an external api which resides in google kubernetes engine.
I want to invoke an api when video get store in google storage so I am using storage trigger but I dont know how to call api in python

I tried the simple trigger on storage

Comment: can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
def getVideoSubtitlesForRecorded(data, context):
    video_name = data['name']
    print(video_name)
    URL = 'http://external_ip:port_no/recorded/video/subtitles/'        # apiendpointlocation
    PARAMS = {'video_name': video_name}
    r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
    print("api Responce : ",r)
```